# How can I make a label visible before the subsequent code is run?

Tags: c#

I have a method that takes several seconds to complete. I want to make a label visible during that time, so I used this code:

```
label.Visible = true;
method();
label.Visible = false;
```

When I run this code, the label's shape appears, but the text and colors don't. If I remove the third line of code, I can see that the label becomes fully visible only after the method completes. How can I make the label fully visible before the method starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `label.Refresh()` to synchronously invalidate and redraw the label.  Here's the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Put the `Refresh` between setting `Visible` to `true` and calling `method`.

Incidentally, if `method` is a long-running operation (as it seems to be), you might want to consider running it on a `BackgroundWorker` so the GUI remains responsive during the operation.  But that means introducing threading into your app, which is comparatively complex, and you may be satisfied with simply repainting the label and leaving the GUI frozen until `method` completes.